# Getting the process id of an invoked PowerShell command

Tags: command-line, powershell, process, wait

Is there anyway of using `ps` to get the pid of a powershell command which is already executing.

For e.g., say I've already executed the following command.

`ls | ? { <where condition> } | % { <some operations> }`

The goal is I open up another powershell window and type in something that allows me to wait for the above to complete.

Any ideas?

Comment: No. You can't wait for that. Have a look at PowerShell Jobs, those might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> allow me to wait for the above to complete.

In that command you are using a ForEach-Object (`%`).

The [ForEach-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-5.1) has a default argument `-Process` that accepts the script block you are providing that is doing the processing for each item in the pipeline.  But that commandlet also offers a `-End {Scriptblock}` argument that will be executed after all the pipeline input has been accepted and processed.  You could use this `-End` block to send your notification somehow.  Perhaps by writing a file or sending an email or whatever else you wanted to notify you.

```
ls | ? { <where condition> } | % { <some operations> } -End { #alert me!}
```